# How do I avoid Picker Fragment from launching again on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have a DatePicker fragment that is working properly until an orientation change occurs.  The user clicks on an EditText line on the UI screen and that launches the DatePcker fragment.  The user selects a date and the code sets the date on the EditText line.  The focus is returned to the EditText line with a blinking cursor.

On orientation change though, the code launches the DatePicker fragment's dialog rather than returning the focus to the EditText line with the blinking cursor.  The previously set date before the change was correctly retained and shows on the EditText line.  I just want the cursor to be set at the end of that EditText line and not have the DatePicker fragment launched again.  Please  advise.

partial Activity file:

```
    ...
    fListenerEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            fListenerEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                fListenerEditText.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

DatePickerFragment file:

```
...
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private EditText txtDate;
private Calendar cal;
private int currentyear;
private int currentmonth;
private int currentday;
private String stringDueDateFrag;

// Empty, parameterless constructor required for DialogFragment that is used by the OS to
// recreate the fragment on device orientation changes.
public DatePickerFragment() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the current date as the default date that we get from a Calendar object, in the DatePicker Dialog.
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog by passing 5 parameters/arguments to the constructor and return it.
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,currentyear,currentmonth,currentday);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
    dialog.setTitle("Select a Due Date");

    return dialog;
}

    public void onDateSet (DatePicker view,int year, int month, int day) {
    txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
    stringDueDateFrag = (month + 1) + "/" + day + "/" + year + " ";
    txtDate.setText(stringDueDateFrag);
    txtDate.setSelection(txtDate.getText().length());
}

    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CardViewActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);

    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: set a boolean flag, make true once the activity has loaded and override onSavedInstance and pass the boolean to the savedInstance bundle, retrieve this value wherever you are doing the fragmentTransaction if the boolean is true then don't do the fragmentTransaction.

Comment: Ok that sounds good.  Can I do all that within the Activity code since that is where the Fragment Transaction code is located?  Or do I have to set up a Listener between the Activity and the Fragment?

Comment: No you can do all of this in your acitvity, you set the flag to true in onCreate, because now you know that your activity is created and on orientation change android retains the savedInstance bundle from which you can restore state. If you reallly want me to write the code then ill do it

Comment: I can try it.  cybersam (below) has also made a suggestion to test the EditText line for emptiness...do you have any thoughts on that solution compared to the one you proposed using flags?

Comment: No his method is way simpler and more suited to your problem

Comment: Understood.  I appreciate your ideas and replies, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During an orientation change, the `Activity` is recreated and the focus is set. Apparently, your `OnFocusChangeListener` is being called to set the focus on your `EditText` view.

If you only want the dialog to display if the `EditText` is empty, try changing `onFocusChange()` to include a test for emptiness. You would need such a test anyway, whenever the focus returns to the `EditText`.

```
fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(); 
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); 
            fListenerEditText.requestFocus(); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: I like it.  What would be more efficient though, your solution or Bhargav's solution (above) that would set a boolean flag on an orienation change?

Comment: I would not add an unnecessary flag that has to be saved and restored, especially when the alternative is to simply change one line of code.

Comment: Meaning the test for emptiness would be less prone to errors and/or more effiicent than a boolean flag test?

Comment: Testing the boolean flag is fast. But during an orientation change, you'd have to also save the flag and then restore it when the Activity is recreated -- a lot of unnecessary work and complexity.

Comment: @AJW Also since the flag is now set to true, your fragment wont work until you set the flag false again, lot of hassle so I suggest you try this out, I will attach the code for my idea anyway, Initially i thought you didnt want the fragment to be loaded on restore state and hence provided that solution which was born from an in accurate understanding of your question, I am however going to attach the code for my answer in case future searchers are interested

Comment: Understood.  Your test looks like it works fine, so thank you.

I used:
if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0)) { ...

Comment: I agree with your version; there is no need to do casting. That's the way I originally had it in my answer, and now I have changed it back.

Comment: Ok great. I have one minor issue to fix. Now when the Date or Time EditText is filled (because the user selected a Date or Time from the Pickers) it takes two clicks to launch the Picker again. This is for the case where a user wanted to change the date or time they previously entered. The first click gets focus and the second click launches the Picker and I am trying to launch the Picker on the first click. So I'm wondering if there is a way to only do the emptiness test on orientation change. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    boolean isActivityLoaded = false;
    static String IS_ACTIVITY_LOADED = "IS_ACTIVITY_LOADED";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        outState.putBoolean(IS_ACTIVITY_LOADED,true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        isActivityLoaded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IS_ACTIVITY_LOADED);
    }

    // SOme place where you are doing the fragment transaction
    void fragmentTransaction() {
        if(!isActivityLoaded) {
            // Dont do transaction.
        }
    }

}
```